# Proving the Mean-value theorem in Evans.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

From PDE Evans, 2nd edition, pages 25-26.

> **THEOREM 2** (Mean Value Formulas for Laplace's equation)**.** *If $u \in C^2(U)$ is harmonic, then $$u(x)=\def\avint{\mathop{\,\rlap{-}\!\!\int}\nolimits} \avint_{\partial B(x,r)}u \, dS=\def\avint{\mathop{\,\rlap{-}\!\!\int}\nolimits} \avint_{B(x,r)} u \, dy$$ for each ball $B(x,r)\subset U$.*
>
> **Proof.** 1. Set $$\phi(r) := \avint_{\partial B(x,r)} u(y) \, dS(y) = \avint_{\partial B(0,1)} u(x+rz) \, dS(z).$$ Then $$\phi'(r)=\avint_{\partial B(0,1)} Du(x+rz) \cdot z \, dS(z)$$ and consequently, using Green's formulas from §C.2, we compute \begin{align}\phi'(r) &= \avint_{\partial B(x,r)} Du(y) \cdot \frac{u-x}r  dS(y) \\ &= \avint_{\partial B(x,r)} \frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}  dS(y) \\ &= \frac rn \avint_{B(x,r)} \Delta u(y) \, dy = 0.\end{align}

Hence $\phi$ is constant, and so $$\phi(r)=\lim_{t \to 0} \phi(t) = \lim_{t \to 0} \avint_{\partial B(x,t)} u(y) \, dS(y) = u(x).$$

The proof continues on but I'm stopping here for this question I need to ask:

Can anyone explain the last line? I understand that $\phi$ is constant since we established that $\phi'(r)=0$ for all harmonic functions $u$. Hence, this is why we can say $\phi(r)=\lim_{t\to 0} \phi(t)$. But how can we establish the last equality, that is, $$\lim_{t \to 0} \avint_{\partial B(x,t)} u(y) \, dS(y)=u(x)?$$

Comment: You could open a separate question on [tex.stackexchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) for the symbol question.

Comment: [How to type average integral?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12561/how-to-type-average-integral)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\def\avint{\mathop{\,\rlap{-}\!\!\int}\nolimits}$

$$
   \avint_{\partial B(x,t)} \, dS(y) = 1
$$
and therefore

$$
\bigl| u(x) - \avint_{\partial B(x,t)} u(y) \, dS(y)\bigr| = \bigl| \avint_{\partial B(x,t)} (u(x) - u(y)) \, dS(y) \bigr| \le 
 \avint_{\partial B(x,t)} |u(x) - u(y)| \, dS(y) \\
\le \max_{y \in \partial B(x,t)} \{ |u(x) - u(y)| \} \quad .
$$

This converges to zero for $t \to 0$ because $u$ is *continuous* at $x$.

Comment: Now, I get that $u$ is continuous, but if we are dealing with $x,y$, does $u$ also need to be **uniformly** continuous? I still can't understand the justification in the last line of your answer.

Comment: @dragon: $u$ is uniformly continuous on each compact set that is not needed here. For fixed $x$ and $\varepsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $|u(x)−u(y)| < \varepsilon $ for all $y$ with $|y - x| < \delta$. If follows that the last expression is less than $\varepsilon$ for $ 0 < t < \delta$.

Comment: @dragon: I do not know what your $\alpha(n)$ is. But anyway, I am sure that the definition is equivalent to $\int f \, dS $ divided by $\int 1 \, dS$. The average of a *constant* function is always defined to be that constant.

Comment: Maybe that definition is equivalent to what you stated. Evans seems to present complicated notation all the time in the book; I too have no idea what $\alpha(n)$ means, but I think it probably has something to do with volume of a ball in higher dimensions.

Comment: Do you know lebesgue points? If yes, this is just the result of Lebesgue points.

Comment: Lebesgue points? Not familiar with that term, though I have taken a course in introduction to measure theory. I looked the term up on Wikipedia, and they had this: $$\lim_{r\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{1}{|B(x,r)|}\int_{B(x,r)} \!|f(y)-f(x)|\,\mathrm{d}y=0.$$ The result by the author is probably derived algebraicallly from this as you already said.

Comment: @ Martin: I do not understand why is the surface area of $|u(x)-u(y)|\le\max_{y\in\partial B(x,t)}\{|u(x)-u(y)|\}$. Is it because the average should roughly less than the maximum of the function? Could you please explain further?

Comment: @math101: Yes. Formally: $\def\avint{\mathop{\,\rlap{-}\!\!\int}\nolimits}$
$\avint_{\partial B(x,t)} |u(x) - u(y)| \, dS(y)
 \le \avint_{\partial B(x,t)} \max_{z \in \partial B(x,t)} \{ |u(x) - u(z)| \} \, dS(y)
 = \max_{z \in \partial B(x,t)} \{ |u(x) - u(z)| \} \avint_{\partial B(x,t)} 1  \, dS(y)
 = \max_{z \in \partial B(x,t)} \{ |u(x) - u(z)| \}$

Comment: In Evans, $\alpha(n) =$ volume of unit ball $B(0,1)$ in $\mathbb R^n$ and $n\alpha(n) = $ surface area of the unit sphere $\partial B(0,1)$ in $\mathbb  R^n$.