# Harmonic in punctured ball and bounded implies harmonic in ball.

Tags: harmonic-functions

If $u$ is harmonic and bounded in $B_1(0)\setminus\{0\}$, then can we say that $u$ is harmonic in $B_1(0)$? I believe the answer is yes and I think the way to show it is by the Mean Value Property... but there is a problem. For $|x|<1/2$ and $|x|<r<1/2$, how do we know that $\frac{1}{|B_r|}\int_{B_r(x)} u(y) dy =u(x)$? Since $u$ is harmonic in the punctured ball, the MVP holds only when $B_r(x)\subset B_1(0)\setminus\{0\}$. How does one get around this problem?

Note we are working in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n\geq 3$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Define
$$
\newcommand{\dashint}{\mathchoice{\rlap{\,\,-}\int}{\rlap{\,-}\int}{\rlap{\ -}\int}{\rlap{\,-}\int}}
\dashint_Af(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac1{|A|}\int_Af(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
$$

Using $(1)$ and $(2)$ from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3341691) and $|S(r,p)|=\omega_{n-1}r^{n-1}$, we get that
$$
\begin{align}
&r_2^{n-1}\frac\partial{\partial r}\dashint_{S(r_2,p_2)}u(x)\,\mathrm{d}\sigma-r_1^{n-1}\frac\partial{\partial r}\dashint_{S(r_1,p_1)}u(x)\,\mathrm{d}\sigma\\
&=\frac1{\omega_{n-1}}\int_{B(r_2,p_2)\setminus B(r_1,p_1)}\Delta u(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\\[6pt]
&=0\tag1
\end{align}
$$
where $r_k\gt|p_k|$ (the origin is inside both spheres).

Thus, for some constant $C$, independent of $p$ (as long as $r\gt|p|$),
$$
r^{n-1}\frac\partial{\partial r}\dashint_{S(r,p)}u(x)\,\mathrm{d}\sigma=C\tag2
$$
Therefore,
$$
\dashint_{S(r,p)}u(x)\,\mathrm{d}\sigma
=\left\{\begin{array}{}
A(p)-\frac{C}{(n-2)\,r^{n-2}}&\text{if }n\ge3\\
A(p)+C\log(r)&\text{if }n=2
\end{array}\right.
\tag3
$$
If $u$ is bounded, then by considering $p=0$, we get $C=0$, and therefore, for $r\gt|p|$,
$$
\dashint_{S(r,p)}u(x)\,\mathrm{d}\sigma=A(p)\tag4
$$
Since $u$ is harmonic away from $0$, the Mean Value Property says that for $r\lt|p|$, 
$$
\dashint_{S(r,p)}u(x)\,\mathrm{d}\sigma=u(p)\tag5
$$
However, because $u$ is smooth away from $0$, and bounded, $\dashint_{S(r,p)}u(x)\,\mathrm{d}\sigma$ is a continuous function of $r$. That is, $A(p)=u(p)$ and we have $(5)$ for all $r$.

Answer (score 4):

The function $u$ is harmonic on a neighborhood of $0$ with $u(x) |x|^{n-2} \to 0$ as $x\to 0$, so it extends to a harmonic function across $0$. (This is a standard result about harmonic functions, but the proof is basically solving the Dirichlet problem on a small punctured ball around $0$ with boundary value $u$, then using the maximum principle and the condition above to ensure that this new solution must just be $u$ itself.)